# Check the existannce of multiple items

Tags: sql, database

I have a table,'intend_items' having following fields

```
Intend_no Product 
0102/18    PC12
0102/18    V13
0102/18    PC12
0102/18    V13
```

In the above case product PC12 is repeated and it is a error here.I want to check how many intend may have same product repeated.

Comment: For future reference, this is what happens when we build a table with adequate primary and/or unique key constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should work for you:

```
SELECT Intend_no, Product, COUNT(*) count
FROM intend_items
GROUP BY Intend_no, Product
having COUNT(*) > 1
```

It will give `Intend_no`, `Product` and number of times they are repeated.

If you want to check only repeated Product and not Intend_no, then try this:

```
SELECT Product, COUNT(*) count
FROM intend_items
GROUP BY Product
having COUNT(*) > 1
```